# Newtonsoft NullValueHandling.Ignore doesn't seem to remove null values when serialising

Tags: c#, json

I expect that I'm just using this in an incorrect way, but when I pass an object through the serialiser with the below settings I was expecting that my null would be removed but it's not happening.

```
ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
```

Object I'm trying to serialise

```
public class Payload
    {
        public Dictionary<string, OtherObjectWhichIsNull> Dict;
    }
```

Instanitation of the object

```
var mockPayload = new Payload
            {
                Dict = new Dictionary<string, OtherObjectWhichIsNull>
                {
                    {
                        "key", null
                    }
                }
            };
```

Serilisation

```
var payloadAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mockPayload, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
            });
```

Result value:

```
{"dict":{"key":null}}
```

Expected value:

```
{"dict":{} }
```

Comment: Expected value is wrong, you will loose entry `{"key", null}` if you do so. Such entry is not in any way *default*, nor empty dictionary have by default entry with key "key", so it can't be restored by deserialization. You have to explain why you expect such a value or what problem you have, see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your understanding of what it does is a little off, but the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm) for it doesn't help. The key part is that this doesn't affect dictionaries - it [only applies to class properties](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/792#issuecomment-180664273).

As an example, if you change `Payload` to this:

```
public class Payload
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

and `mockPayload` to this (I'm only explicitly initialising `Test` to `null` so it's clear):

```
var mockPayload = new Payload
{
    Test = null,
    Test2 = "hi"
};
```

then the output you'll get will be `{"test2":"hi"}`.